# Get UserName and Make UserName reactive after Vue Authentication

Tags: vue.js, authentication, axios, vuex

I am having trouble getting user data and making user data reactive after the user has logged In.
Without using Store i am getting the user information but I am unable to make it reactive. So I tried storing user information in store. Now I am having getting that data as well.
I have a login form in LOGINCOMPONENT.VUE that has two input fields email and password.

```
<form @submit.prevent="login">
  <input placeholder="Email" type="email" v-model="formData.email">
  <input placeholder="Password" type="password" v-model="formData.password">
</form>
```

Script portion:

```
export default {
  name: 'LoginPage',
  data() {
    return {
      formData: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      this.$axios.post('login', this.formData).then(async (res) => {
        await localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res));
        await localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
        this.$router.push('/');

        console.log(res);
        this.$store.dispatch('userDataAction', res); --->>> Using Store to take user data
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Login process goes well and user token is generated.
This is my store.

```
const state = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token') || null,
  userData: {},
};

const getters = {
  getUserData: state => state.userData,
  loggedIn: state => state.token != null,
};

const mutations = {
  userDataMutation(state, userData) {
    state.userData = userData;
  },
};

const actions = {
  userDataAction(context, credentials) {
    const userData = {
      username: credentials.username,
      email: credentials.email,
      firstName: credentials.first_name,
      lastName: credentials.last_name,
    };
    context.commit('userDataMutation', userData);
  },
};
```

Finally in my HEADERCOMPONENT.VUE where i am showing "SIGN IN" if user is not logged In and "HELLO USERNAME" if user is logged in.

```
export default {
  name: 'HeaderComponent',
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getUserData', 'loggedIn']),
  },
};
```

Template:

```
<div> {{ loggedIn ? getUserData.username : 'Sign In' }} </div>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what actually is your issue?

Comment: Are you changing the value of the state property `token` anywhere? Setting it in `localStorage` won't automatically update what is in the store.

Comment: @skirtle: Thanks Man.. Yeah I didnot store the token in state via mutation.